# File Path Details | Using command prompt or any script

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, scripting, command-prompt, file-format

Can anybody help me with some command prompt details/ script detail/python programming on how to get file details?

Scenario:

Folder contains many subfolders -- > how to get to know what file formats are present in the folders and how to get path of all those files.

Like, I need, distinct file names/formats/path of the files present under a folder/subfolders

Is there anyway possible to get that or manual effort will only be required?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To recursively list all files in folders and sub-folders in Python:

**Glob** [[docs]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

```py
from glob import glob
glob("**", recursive=True)
```

**OS Walk** [[docs]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

```py
import os
list(os.walk("./"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, csv

import glob

import pandas as pd

import ast

dir_path = r'<path of directory>'

extension_output_path = r"<path of output file. Path where u want to save output in csv format>"

output_filenames_path = r"<path of output file. Path where u want to save output in csv format>"

exts = set(f.split('.')[-1] for dir,dirs,files in os.walk(dir_path) for f in files if '.' in f)

exts = list(set(exts))

subdirs = [x[0] for x in os.walk(dir_path)]

print(exts)

big_list = []

bigg_list = []

def FindMaxLength(lst):

 maxLength = max(map(len, lst))

 return maxLength

for dirs in subdirs:

 split_dirs = dirs.split('\\')

 big_list.append(split_dirs)

big_list_count = FindMaxLength(big_list)

for subdis in big_list:

 count_val = big_list_count - len(subdis)

 bigg_list.append(subdis + ['']* count_val + ['/'.join(subdis)])

output_list = []

path_list = []

for subbs in bigg_list:

 big_dict = {}

 for ext in exts:

  tifCounter = len(glob.glob1(subbs[-1],"*."+ext))

  filenames = glob.glob1(subbs[-1],"*."+ext)

  if filenames != []:

    val = list(map((subbs[-1]+'/').__add__,filenames))

    if len(val) >1:

      for li in val:

        path_list.append([ext, li])

    else:

      path_list.append([ext]+val)

  if tifCounter != 0:

    big_dict[ext] = tifCounter

 output_list.append(subbs+ [big_dict])

columns_row = ['col']* (big_list_count + 1)+ ['val'] + exts

with open(extension_output_path,'w', newline='') as csv_file:

 csv_wr = csv.writer(csv_file)

 csv_wr.writerow(columns_row)

 csv_wr.writerows(output_list)

cv = pd.read_csv(extension_output_path)

for index, row in cv.iterrows():

  for ext in exts:

    if row['val'] != '{}' and ext in ast.literal_eval(row['val']):

      cv.loc[index,ext] = ast.literal_eval(row['val'])[ext]

del cv['val']

cv.to_csv(extension_output_path, index=False)

with open(output_filenames_path,'w', newline='') as csv_file:

 csv_wr = csv.writer(csv_file)

 csv_wr.writerow(['extension', 'filename'])

 csv_wr.writerows(path_list)

print("completed")
```

This output file will contain folder/subfolder path with extension's count.